# keep x number of lines in scrolling div

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure how to title this question, but basically I am streaming output of a server process to a web browser and placing it in a variable called result in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        namespace = '/socket';
        var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += msg.data;
            });
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The challenge I am having is eventually if the process runs long enough the browser crashes, assumingly from that variable being too large.  I want to keep lets say 250 lines and keep updating it while removing anything past 250 lines.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your text into separate lines, remove all of the lines beyond the limit, and then set the text again. It'd look something like this:

```
    socket.on('my_response', function(msg) {
        var lineBreak = '<br>'; // or whatever you're using to delineate lines
        var currentText = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML + msg.data;
        var lines = currentText.split(lineBreak); // split your text into lines
        lines = lines.slice(-250); // only keep the most recent lines
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = lines.join(lineBreak);
    });
```